# yasm/nasm not found or too old. Use --disable-yasm for a crippled build

Tags: android

Getting The above error while Integrating FFMPEG library in Android. Following is the Screen Shot. Can someone Help me integrating this library?
I am Using Ubuntu OS for implementing this.
[image]

Comment: Same problem, google solutions has failed. `yum install yasm` dont make changes. `No package yasm available.` ffmpeg 3.0

Comment: I solved it by installing yasm

Comment: @Florida Try adding another repo or just find the package at another source.

Comment: I fixed this, but i don't remember how now @DanielGray

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Just install yasm

> sudo apt-get install yasm

That worked for me

Comment: For those who wants to install yasm on MAC, Check this link http://macappstore.org/yasm/

Answer (score 16):

In order to install `yasm` on Ubuntu, try this below:

```
sudo apt-get install yasm
```

On MacOS

```
#http://macappstore.org/yasm/
brew install yasm
```

Answer (score 5):

Install yasm. The command:

> `sudo yum install yasm`

worked on my CentOS server perfectly.

Comment: what should i di if it says it is not found?

Answer (score 1):

In mingw-64 install command is

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-yasm
```

Answer (score 0):

**As an extra tip for windows users with git bash who might have the same problem.**

If you are on windows and you have installed FFMPEG from the website using git bash and the `ffmpeg-x.x.x.tar.bz2` file, and faced the same problem. You should use the link for windows (in get the packages), and then unzip and go to `bin/ffmpeg` to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue under OpenSuse, you can install with:

```
sudo zypper install yasm yasm-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

In case yum fails to install it, this might help:

```
   dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
   dnf install yasm
```